# Having trouble trying to fade In and Out text for setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have been figuring out ways to fade out and fade in words for my function. I am still new to javascript so I really cannot think of other ways. My code still hard refreshes even when I add in fadein and out so I am asking for help. Thank you

```
var words = [
"Aaron",
"John",
"Megan"
];

index = 0;
function wordslide(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.title-case:eq(0)').html('<div class="img-title">'+words[index]+'</div>').fadeIn();
    });
    index++;
    if (index == words.length) { index = 0}
        setTimeout(wordslide, 2000);
}
wordslide();
```

Comment: I see a couple of problems with the first `setTimeout` call. You're not supplying an interval, just the function - and the bracketing is wrong in the function (`.fadeIn()` is javascript but you've included it inside the html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements are fully visible when they are created.
Try to add `.hide()` before `.fadeIn()`, this should make the names being faded in.

```
$('.title-case:eq(0)').html('<div class="img-title">'+words[index]+'</div>').hide().fadeIn();
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me appreciate your help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

it looks like instead of setTimeout, what you are looking for is [set Interval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). That might help to clean up some of the complexity of your code.

After that just call hide or fadeOut before fadeIn like Tschitsch suggested.

Using setInterval we could rewrite your function as:

```html
var words = [
"Aaron",
"John",
"Megan"
];

index = 0;

var myWordFadeInterval = setInterval(function(){
wordslide();
}, 2000);

function wordslide(){
        $('.title-case:eq(0)').html('<div class="img-title">'+words[index]+'</div>.fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000)');
        index++;
        if (index == words.length) 
          index = 0
}


//when you want to stop your interval call:
//clearInterval(myWordFadeInterval);
```

The first parameter of your fadeIn/fadeOut is time [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadein.asp)